# Inferring key names with Typescript

Tags: typescript, intellisense

The following code works well in Visual Studio Code:

```
type MyType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
};

type MyTypes = { [name: string]: MyType }; 

const MY_TYPES:MyTypes = {
    ONE: { id: 0, name: 'name0' },
    TWO: { id: 1, name: 'name1' }
};

console.log(MY_TYPES.ONE); //Intellisense error
console.log(MY_TYPES['ONE']);
```

Both the log statements compile and output the same thing, but the first one generates an error in VS Code and states 'Property 'ONE' does not exist on type'. Is there any other way for me to structure my code so that VS Code can automatically infer/autocomplete that MY_TYPES has property names ONE and TWO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [indexed object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) then you can only access the properties using an index:

```
type MyTypes = { [name: string]: MyType };
console.log(MY_TYPES["ONE"]);
```

That's because the compiler only knows that the object has keys of type string, it doesn't know the specific keys.

If you want to be able to access the properties using the dot notation, then you need to do this:

```
type MyTypes = {
    ONE: MyType;
    TWO: MyType;
}
console.log(MY_TYPES.ONE);
```

You can however just do this:

```
type MyTypes = {
    ONE: MyType;
    TWO: MyType;
} 

const MY_TYPES = {
    ONE: { id: 0, name: 'name0' },
    TWO: { id: 1, name: 'name1' }
};
```

And the compiler will infer the type for `MY_TYPES`.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use your approach but to declare MyTypes as an interface instead. Works just as well, with some added flexibility as I've understood it.